# Anacondaのインストール先でないディレクトリにも関連ファイルがある

Tags: python, anaconda

Anacondaを `E:\anaconda3` というディレクトリにインストールしました。
navigatorやpromptはしっかりそのディレクトリに保存されましたが、関連しているであろう以下のファイルが `C:\users\owner` の下に保存されてしまいました。

```
.conda
.continuum
.ipython
.keras
.matplotlib
.spyder-py3
```

anaconda関連はEドライブに揃えたいのですが、これらがCにインストールされるのは避けられないのでしょうか。
また、再インストールする以外に解決する方法があるでしょうか。
PATHを手動で通すのはWindowsではやったことがありませんので、そうするしかない場合は詳しく教えていただけませんか。

Answer (score 0):

最初のこれは変更できるかもしれない説明はありましたが、その実例的なものは無さそうです。
しかもこれよりも先に参照される`.condarc`というファイルがあり、それの場所は変更出来そうもないですね。
また`.anaconda`とか`AppData`の更に下の所にもディレクトリがあるようです。

- .conda

---

こちらはちょっと検索したくらいでは情報が見つかりませんでした。

- .continuum

---

以下の3つについては環境変数を設定することで出来そうな説明があります。

- .ipython
- .keras
- .matplotlib

---

以下 .spyer-py3 については、議論はされているようですが、まだ実装には至っていないようですね。

- .spyder-py3

---

他にも Jupyter-Lab/Notebook とか使う物が増えれば必要な設定も増えると思われます。

---

**.conda について**

この辺の記事に説明がされていそうですが、標準的な設定の例らしきものはあっても変更例的なものは無く、検索しても無さそうでした。
[Using the .condarc conda configuration file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html)
[Administering a multi-user conda installation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html)
[Conda configuration](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html)

設定内容を表示するコマンドとして`conda info`や`conda config --show`というのがあって、それを見ると他にもフォルダがあるようですね。
抜粋するとこんなものがあります。(`All Users`で`C:\Anaconda3`にインストールした際の情報)

```
    active env location : C:\Anaconda3

       user config file : C:\Users\UserName\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\UserName\.condarc

       base environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Anaconda3\etc\conda

          package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\UserName\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\UserName\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
```

そうしたディレクトリ以外のよく使う設定・変更については説明記事が見つかります。
[Anaconda備忘録](https://qiita.com/tsugar/items/af716954e8e1b94e9965)
[Anaconda でよく使うコマンド一覧](https://qiita.com/naz_/items/84634fbd134fbcd25296)
[【Anacondaの使い方】よく使うcondaコマンド一覧【チートシート】](https://hogelog.com/python/conda-command.html)

ちなみにAnacondaのディレクトリを移動するには、環境保存→アンインストール→再インストール→環境復元という手順になるようです。
[Moving Anaconda from one directory to another](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/)
[Managing environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) 保存と復元を含む
[Uninstalling Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/uninstall/)
[Installation](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/)

---

**.ipython について**

以下のように`IPYTHONDIR`という環境変数にディレクトリを設定しておけば出来そうな感じです。

[Overview of the IPython configuration system](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/config.html)

> - If the ipython-dir command line flag is given, its value is used.
> - If not, the value returned by IPython.paths.get_ipython_dir() is used. This function will first look at the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable and then default to `~/.ipython`. Historical support for the `IPYTHON_DIR` environment variable will be removed in a future release.
>
> For most users, the configuration directory will be `~/.ipython`.

---

**.keras について**

以下のように`KERAS_BACKEND`という環境変数にディレクトリを設定しておけば出来そうな感じです。

[Keras backends](https://keras.io/ja/backend/)

> バックエンドの切り替え
> 少なくとも一度Kerasを実行したら，以下にあるKerasの設定ファイルを見つけるでしょう．
>
> ```
> $HOME/.keras/keras.json
> ```
>
> もしそこにこのファイルがなければ，あなたが作成できます．
> Windows ユーザへ注意: `$HOME` を `%USERPROFILE%` に変更してください．

> 環境変数`KERAS_BACKEND`も定義することができて，かつあなたの設定ファイルで定義されているものを上書きします:

---

**.matplotlib について**

以下のように`MPLCONFIGDIR`という環境変数にディレクトリを設定しておけば出来そうな感じです。

[matplotlib configuration and cache directory locations](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/users/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations)

> On Unix-like systems, this directory is generally located in your `HOME` directory under the .config/ directory.
> In addition, users have a cache directory. On Unix-like systems, this is separate from the configuration directory by default. To locate your .cache/ directory, use matplotlib.get_cachedir():

> If you would like to use a different configuration directory, you can do so by specifying the location in your `MPLCONFIGDIR` environment variable -- see Setting environment variables in Linux and macOS. Note that `MPLCONFIGDIR` sets the location of both the configuration directory and the cache directory.

[Environment variables](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/users/faq/environment_variables_faq.html)

> **MPLCONFIGDIR**
> This is the directory used to store user customizations to Matplotlib, as well as some caches to improve performance. If `MPLCONFIGDIR` is not defined, `HOME/.config/matplotlib` and `HOME/.cache/matplotlib` are used on Linux, and `HOME/.matplotlib` on other platforms, if they are writable. Otherwise, the Python standard library's tempfile.gettempdir is used to find a base directory in which the matplotlib subdirectory is created.

---

**.spyder-py3 について**

このIssueで議論しているが状況はあまり進展していない。
[Set the path of Spyder Configuration Folder #4150](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4150)

以下にSpyder起動時だけ`USERPROFILE`の環境変数を変更する裏技的な対処方法がコメントされていますが、Anaconda Navigatorからの起動に使えるかは不明です。
[Here's how to run spyder in portable mode in Windows without changing the code:](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4150#issuecomment-782893106)

ただそれでディレクトリの変更は出来ても、スクリプトのデバッグ時やSpyderから起動するツールでは書き変えられた`USERPROFILE`が使われるでしょうから、それらはまともに動かなくなる可能性が高いですね。